# Mercurial build on push

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration

I'd like for a build to be done (on the server) each time a push is made to our central Mercurial repository.
Builds are usually kicked off on our build server by running a Visual Build file either manually or via a scheduled task.

What are the ways of achieving this?

Simple, low impact solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 15):

As Pablo suggested, you can do this with a hook, but you'll need an *incoming* hook on the server side. This hook runs "after a changeset has been pulled, pushed, or unbundled into the local repository" ([hgrc manpage](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks)).

Edit the `.hg/hgrc` file of the repository located on the server and define your build hook as follows:

```
[hooks]
incoming = /path/to/executable-build-script
```

Of course, the build script called here just needs to be a trigger for whatever build process you actually use.

Note that an *incoming* hook runs for every single changeset in a push. If you don't want this, use a *changegroup* hook -- it runs only once for each push, no matter how many changesets it carries.

Comment: I'll try this out. I'm just curious as to how doing a push to the server can actually execute a process on the server. I was under the impression Mercurial was file based and that there was no Mercurial service actually running on our server.

Comment: Not really a service, but the plain `hg` command is executed on the server whenever you talk with it. In case of *HTTP* access, the web server runs some scripts which then run a Mercurial installation on the server side. In case of *SSH*, your local `hg` uses SSH to log in to the server and that way runs the remote Mercurial installation. Summarized, the only service running on the remote site is a web or SSH server which run `hg` similar as you do it locally.

Answer (score 5):

Another way, in addition to the hooks that Pablo mentions, is to set up a continuous integration server, like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). Then you could ask TeamCity to monitor your repository, pull new changesets and start the visual build script for you.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer**

These findings are for tortoisehg client and mercurial server behind apache on win32.

**Try #1**

The naive solution would be to make your push kick off the build.

In `.hg\hgrc`

```
[hooks]
incoming=.hg\build.py
```

In `build.py`

```py
os.system('\Progra~2\Micros~2.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /build release project.sln > logfile')
```

***Problem***

What you'll find is that, after a push, the tortoise hg client won't return until your os.system call returns. This may or not be acceptable. In my shop a build took about 20 minutes, and my boss deemed that unacceptable.

**Try #2**

My solution was for the hook to return immediately after creating a REQUESTBUILD file to the root directory.

In `.hg\hgrc`

```
[hooks]
incoming = .hg\write_buildrequest_file.bat
```

In `.hg\write_buildrequest_file.bat`

```
echo REQUESTBUILD > \REQUESTBUILD
```

Meanwhile, I had a python script running in an infinite loop, checking for the presence of REQUESTBUILD.

In `.hg\monitor_buildrequest_file.py`

```py
import popen2, time, os
import subprocess

while True:
    if os.path.exists("\REQUESTBUILD"):
        os.system("del \REQUESTBUILD")
        os.chdir("/yourrepo/.hg")
        retcode = subprocess.call("\python27\python.exe build.py")
    else:
        time.sleep(10)
```

`build.py` would generate an HTML file of results, which the submitter would have to pull via their web browser.

There are other issues (pushes while a build is commencing, saving historical results, building out of the working directory vs copying elsewhere) but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [handle repository events with hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html).

So, after `commit` event you need to run a script that will perform your build accordingly.

Comment: From your link: "and the command causes a hook to run, that hook runs on your system". This is a problem because I want the build to be done on the build server itself, not on the machine of the person pushing the changes.